# Why is it undecidable to check the emptiness and finiteness of a context-sensitive grammar?

Tags: context-free, context-sensitive, decidability

Context-sensitive languages have context-sensitive grammars, and context-free languages have context-free grammars. Using context-free grammars, we can decide the finiteness and emptiness of context-free languages. Why can't we decide these properties of context-sensitive languages in the same manner, using context-sensitive grammars?

I want to understand the intuition rather than the details.

Comment: (Fuzzy as my memories are, a "sub-question": have another look at the proofs of above claims about CFGs - can you reproduce one of them for CSGs?)

Comment: @greybeard I want to understand intuition. Not details.

Comment: Same as https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/144815/why-linear-bounded-automata-emptiness-and-finiteness-isnt-decidable

Comment: @yuval if I write my own answer, could you correct that if I do anything wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the idea in a nutshell:

- Given a Turing machine $M$, we can construct a context-free grammar $G$ such that if $M$ halts then $\overline{L(G)} = \{t\}$, where $t$ is the transcript of the halting computation of $M$, and if $M$ doesn't halt then $\overline{L(G)} = \emptyset$. 
   Consequently, given a context-free grammar $G$, determining whether $L(G) = \Sigma^*$ is undecidable.
- Given a Turing machine $M$, we can construct a context-sensitive grammar $G$ such that if $M$ halts then $L(G) = \{t\}$, where $t$ is the transcript of the halting computation of $M$, and $L(G) = \emptyset$ otherwise. 
   Consequently, given a context-sensitive grammar $G$, determining whether $L(G) =\emptyset$ or whether $L(G)$ is finite are both undecidable.

(A *transcript* is the sequence of configurations describing the execution of the machine, and a configuration consists of the tape contents, the head location, and the state.)

The context-free grammar in the first bullet generates "illegal" transcripts. This requires nondeterminism, and indeed, determining whether $L(G) = \Sigma^*$ for a *deterministic* context-free grammar (i.e., a context-free grammar corresponding to a deterministic pushdown automaton) is decidable.

The context-sensitive grammar in the second bullet is easiest to describe via the equivalent computation model of linear bounded automata: it is easy to construct a linear bounded automaton for the given language. This time the construction requires no nondeterminism, and so determining whether $L(G) = \emptyset$ or whether $L(G)$ is finite is undecidable even for "deterministic context-sensitive grammars", i.e., the subclass of context-sensitive grammars corresponding to deterministic linear bounded automata.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130613/discussion-on-answer-by-yuval-filmus-why-is-it-undecidable-to-check-the-emptines).